# Adding string filter and sorting to datacolumn gridview yii2

Tags: php, gridview, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

```
['header'=>'Bill No',
'attribute'=>'billid',
'filter'=>ArrayHelper::map(Bills::find()->all(),'id','billno'),
'format' =>'text',
'value'=>  function($data){
    return ($data->billid)?$data->bill->billno:'Nope';
}]
```

By using this code, I am getting a drop-down box as a filter, but bill number is going to be in 10000's. So I want an input type text as a filter for my foreign key.

```
Relationship:
DB Table:
Cashbook
Column: billed

On
DB Table:
Bills
Column:id
```

And I want to extract bill no from the id for this filter. Please Help
I want to search and sort for billno.

Answer (score 0):

A better alternative is to use [`kartik\Select2`](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2) so that you can have the dropdown and search both 2 in 1.

There is an [**`option`**](https://select2.org/configuration/options-api) for the minimum number of character that you have to type in to open the drop-down rather than opening the drop-down with 1000's of options at once by clicking on it.

> `minimumInputLength`: Minimum number of characters required to start a search.

```
[
    'header' => 'Bill No',
    'attribute' => 'billid',
    'filter' => \kartik\widgets\Select2::widget([
        'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Bills::find()->all(),'id','billno'),
        'model' => $searchModel,
        'attribute' => 'billid',
        'options' => [
            'placeholder' => 'Bill No',
            'id' => 'bill_id',
        ],
        'theme' => \kartik\widgets\Select2::THEME_BOOTSTRAP,
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'allowClear' => true,
            'minimumInputLength' => '3',
        ],
    ]),
    'format' =>'text',
    'value'=>  function($data){
      return ($data->billid)?$data->bill->billno:'Nope';
    }
],
```

Hope that helps you out

Comment: Still can you guide me how to attach input text for foreign key. I need that functionality